# Add meta box for Featured Image caption in wp-admin/post-new.php

Tags: posts, metabox

I want to add a meta box in my `wp-admin/post-new.php` page. Someone please help me.

I've recently searched for solutions but can't find the answer in any tutorials I've read. I try to modify html codes by inspecting element features in my browser, but I don't know how to save the changes.

Comment: So just to clarify, have you got a metabox working and you need help *saving* the data, or are you stuck with everything?

Comment: I stuck with all...